# Can't get Chrome extension content script (document_start) to inject synchronous third-party script into <head> block

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have a third-party `<script>` that utilizes `MutationObserver` for conditionally transforming newly added nodes, and for obvious reasons is required to be included inside of the `<head>` block.

If I manually update the source of the Website and include the third-party `<script>` inside of the `<head>` block - everything works correctly, and the third-party `<script>` is able to observe all mutations that occur.

However, if I use a Chrome extension to inject the third-party `<script>` into the `<head>` block of the Website - the third-party `<script>` is being properly injected into the `<head>` block of the Website, but is observing very few mutations, comparatively speaking.

My review of the Chrome > DevTools > Network panel revealed that the third-party `<script>` **starts** its' **load** sequence after a variable number of requests belonging to `<img>`, `<script>`, `<etc>` elements inside of the `<body>` block. Following this discovery, and a bit more research - I was able to confirm that Chrome **does** in fact default to loading dynamically injected `<script>` tags asynchronously.

Below you'll find the relevant `manifest.json` configuration being used, as well as the several different methods for which I've attempted to inject the third-party `<script>`.

**manifest.json**

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "js": ["head.content-script.js"]
}]
```

**head.content-script.js (attempt #1)**

```
document.write('<script async="false" src="//third-party-js.com/third-party.js"></script>');
```

**head.content-script.js (attempt #2)**

```
var script = document.createElement('script');

script.async = false;
script.src = ('//third-party-js.com/third-party.js');

document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
```

**head.content-script.js (attempt #3)**

```
var script = document.createElement('script'),
    code = '(' + function() {
        document.write('<script src="//third-party-js.com/third-party.js"><\/scr' + 'ipt>');
    } + ')()';

script.textContent = code;
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.remove();
```

**head.content-script.js (attempt #4)**

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(addedNode) {
            if (addedNode.nodeName === 'HEAD') {
                var script = document.createElement('script');

                script.async = false;
                script.src = ('//third-party-js.com/third-party.js');

                addedNode.appendChild(script);
            }
        });
    });
});

observer.observe(document, {
    'childList': true,
    'subtree': true
});
```

Has anyone else experienced this challenge? I am also open to suggestions if there is a better approach to doing this. I would even open to using something like [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) for modifying the response on-the-fly. Again, my primary objective with the Chrome extension is to end up with a smooth, reliable page load - as if I had manually updated the source of the Website to include the third-party `<script>`.

Comment: I guess, Chrome enqueues the non-original injected content. There's probably nothing you can do about it except injecting the script content (fetched previously and stored locally) inside `<script>` tag. However, if script contents is dynamically changed (that is you can't just inline it as a string in your content script), you'll have to work around the messaging/chrome.storage delay, so the behavior you want won't be 100% guaranteed.

Comment: On second thought, try `document.write` inside attempt #4.

Comment: Using `document.write` in attempt #4 results in 2 of the same `<script>` tags being inserted into `<head>` and no `<body>` block gets created.

Comment: Huh, try writing inside the injected script element: `script.textContent = "document.write('...........')"`, appendChild.

Comment: The bug is already reported: https://crbug.com/634381. You may want to weigh in with the details.

Comment: Ugh... so I'm basically going to have to do something like check cache (e.g. localStorage, etc.) for previously fetched content of third-party `<script>` for that page URL, and if it doesn't exist in cache then immediately and asynchronously fetch content of third-party `<script>` for that page URL and `document.write` some invalid, unterminated permanently render blocking markup (white page). Once fetched content of third-party script has been retrieved I'll then cache it and `window.location.reload(true)`, which when all put together should (in theory) look very similar. Agreed? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a flawlessly working solution. Credit goes to **wOxxOm**:

**head.content-script.js**

```
var url = '//third-party-js.com/third-party.js',
    urlEncoded = window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(url))),
    urlContent = localStorage.getItem(urlEncoded);

if (!urlContent) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if ((xhr.readyState === 4) && (xhr.status === 200)) {
            localStorage.setItem(urlEncoded, xhr.responseText);
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    };

    xhr.send(null);

    document.write('<script src="' + url + '"><\/script>');
} else {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = urlContent;
    document.documentElement.append(script);
}
```

Comment: Does not work in Firefox "the operation is insecure". Also calling reload on a POST request would re-submit a form which is bad for the user.